# Choosing a free Olap server for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, olap, olap-cube

Each client has its own postgresql 9.5 db.
Client registration leads to the creation of a new database.
I can not choose free Olap server preferably on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The structure of the tables is the same for each of the clients

Comment: what kind of OLAP server do you need? XMLA/MDX is must have, or your final goal is reports generation (pivot tables/charts)?

Comment: XMLA / MDX Does not matter, generation reports pivot tables

Comment: for pivot tables you can check products mentioned in my SO profile (according to SO rules I cannot promote it here)